# Testing for duplicate usernames from a .txt file

Tags: c++

i wanted to try to code a log in/register program. Using an external .txt file as my database, i wanted to keep the 'registered' users and passwords in it.
Problem: I cant really test the duplicates of the usernames

```
    // Currently stuck here
    //Issue is that the if statment is not testing the way i want it to (comparing the usernames)

    //The .txt file that i am using contains the content: "Usernames: "

    //getline(myfile,line) returns "Usernames:" which is not really finding if there are any duplicates of usernames


    ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());

    while(getline(myfile,line)){

            cout<< line;

            if(line.find("Username: " + userregtry) == string::npos){

                    myfile.close();

                    ofstream writein(filename.c_str(),ios::app);

                    writein<< "Username: " << userregtry << "\n" ;
            }
            else{

                    cout<< "\nThis username has been taken\nPlease try another username: ";
            }
    }
```

Comment: In order to check for duplicates you must save the previously read usernames into some kind of data structure. That's the first requirement. Simple choice would be a `std::set`. Also your file handling is wrong, you can't mix input and output to the same file in that way.

Comment: slightly offtopic: storing passwords logins/passwords as plain text is security risk: usually you store some sort of hash of login/password, and on authentification you calculate this hash from user input and check it against what you store in database

Comment: In your comments you wrote, that in your file the String "Usernames: " does exist, while you are searching for "Username: " (without the trailing 's')

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, use [boost property_map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html)

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the input! @AndrewKashpur, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TomMekken oh yeah, i meant username, a typo there

Answer (score 0):

**Supposing there is one name per line**

There are several problems :

- if the name is not on the first line you consider the name is absent and you close the file, stopping the search
- if the name is present on the first line you warn then continue and if there is a second line a priori without the name you consider the name is absent
- if the file is empty it will stay empty

You need to look at all the lines before to consider the name is absent or not.

A solution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string filename = "/tmp/foo";
  string userregtry;

  cout << "\nPlease enter username: ";

  for (;;) {
    if (!(cin >> userregtry))
      break;

    ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
    bool found = false;
    string line;

    while (getline(myfile,line)) {
      if (line.find("Username: " + userregtry) != string::npos) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    myfile.close();

    if (found)
      cout<< "\nThis username has been taken\nPlease try another username: ";
    else {
      ofstream writein(filename.c_str(),ios::app);
      writein<< "Username: " << userregtry << "\n" ;
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Execution from an empty file :

```
/tmp % ./a.out
Please enter username: aze
/tmp % ./a.out
Please enter username: aze
This username has been taken
Please try another username: qsd
/tmp % ./a.out
Please enter username: qsd
This username has been taken
Please try another username: aze
This username has been taken
Please try another username: iop
/tmp % cat foo
Username: aze
Username: qsd
Username: iop
```

---

**Supposing the file contains one line `Usernames: name1 name2 ... namen`**

There are several problems :

- Your code doesn't find the name except if it is in the first position
- When you add a new name you loose all the others
- Username or Username**s** ?

A solution where the unique line is not terminated :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string filename = "/tmp/foo";
  string line;

  {
    ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());

    if (getline(myfile,line))
      line += ' '; // to have a space before and after each name including the last
  }

  string userregtry;

  cout << "Please enter username: ";

  for (;;) {
    if (!(cin >> userregtry))
      return 0;

    if (line.find(' ' + userregtry + ' ') != string::npos)
      cout << "This username has been taken\nPlease try another username: ";
    else {
      ofstream writein(filename.c_str(),ios::app);

      if (line.empty())
        writein << "Usernames: ";
      else
        writein << ' ';

      writein << userregtry;
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Execution from an empty file :

```
Please enter username: aze
/tmp % ./a.out
Please enter username: aze
This username has been taken
Please try another username: qsd
/tmp % ./a.out
Please enter username: aze
This username has been taken
Please try another username: qsd
This username has been taken
Please try another username: wxc
/tmp % cat foo ; echo "#"
Usernames: aze qsd wxc#
```